# Ubuntu - 12.04 Update manager and software center is not working

Tags: 12.04, software-center, python, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed in my machine. Update manager and software center is not working after applying some packages through update manager. The following is the error trace I got, when I executed the command update-manager on a terminal.

I tried to resolved this by **reinstalling python** once and then **upgrading the python to 2.7.4**. But the issue remains same.

Can anybody please help me on this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 33, in 
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 41, in 
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in 
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 15, in 
    import encodings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 32, in 

ImportError: cannot import name aliases
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 8, in 
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in 
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 15, in 
    import encodings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 32, in 

ImportError: cannot import name aliases
```

Comment: **Don't** mess with the Python system binary as it will get you into trouble as you see now. Only use the Ubuntu packaged version of Python and create a **pyenv** if you need a specific version of Python for development. Please include in your question more details on how you installed the other Python version and how you tried to revert it by "reinstalling". Then I may be able to help you get this sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get rid of this by reinstalling the following packages.

1. python (Upgraded from 2.7.3 to 2.7.5)
2. python2.7-minimal
3. python-support